# Getting the Windows 8.1 touch keyboard to automatically capitalise the beginning of sentences

Tags: windows-8.1, on-screen-keyboard

I cannot find any settings in Windows 8.1 to make the touch keyboard capitalise automatically.  Is there a way to enable/add this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the keyboard, but the application that capitalizes. MS Word, LibreOffice and Open Office, for example, all have settings to capitalize the first word. Just turn it off when copying e e cummings poetry or archie and mehitabel.

Comment: And +1 for the e e cummings reference!